# what is the parameter defination of .removeClass() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in my case i am using `.removeClass()` but when using this then asking 4 parameter value

html code is

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
<div id="in-put" class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="txtStrongPassword">Income</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            <input type="text" id="txtIncome" class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Your annual income after taxes">
        </div>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
        <span class="help-block">Success</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and `jquery` asking parameters are-

[image]

i understand first two but remaining 2 parameter i can't understand what is this or how to use them.

I want to manipulate **#in-put** div

Comment: that's jqueryui, you could [read the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/removeClass/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Default jQuery** `.removeClass()` function has only one parameter, which is `className`.

Check documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

---

If you are using **jQuery UI**, then you have more parameters:

**className:** *One or more class names (space separated) to be removed from the class attribute of each matched element.*

**duration:** *A string or number determining how long the animation will run.*

**easing:** *A string indicating which easing function to use for the transition.*

**complete:** *A function to call once the animation is complete, called once per matched element.*

Check documentation here: http://api.jqueryui.com/removeClass/

Answer (score 0):

Check the [doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/removeclass/)

Last two parameters are - `easing` and `complete` (callback)

**easing** (default: swing)

A string indicating which easing function to use for the transition.
complete

**Complete**:

A function to call once the animation is complete, called once per matched element.

Answer (score 0):

`className` - The name of the class you will be removing (`SomeClassName`).

`speed` - A string or number determining how long the animation will run (Default is `400ms`).

`easing` - A string indicating which easing function to use for the transition (Default is `swing`).

`callback` - A function to call once the animation is completed.